# cluster most similar words with pre trained word2vec model using k means clustering

Tags: python, list, tuples, k-means, word2vec

I have build a word2vec model containing the sentences of several scientific research papers and retrieved the top 100 most similar words for the term "online_platform":

```py
# Create a model with 300 dimensions and a context window of 6 words.
# Only consider words that appear at least in 10 documents. Use 3 CPU
# cores for estimating the model.

model_online_platform = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences_online_platform, window = 4, min_count = 10, workers=3)
online_platform_most_similar = model_online_platform.most_similar("online_platform", topn=100)
```

Here are some of the most similar words:

```
most_similar_words=[('event', 0.6746241450309753),
 ('date', 0.612309992313385),
 ('stems', 0.6009981632232666),
 ('draws', 0.5935811996459961),
 ('company', 0.5848336219787598), ...]
```

From this list of tuples I retrived only the words, leaving out the similarity scores:

`first_tuple_elements = ['event', 'date', 'stems', 'draws', 'company',...]`

Then I used a Pre-Trained Word2Vec (glove-wiki-gigaword-300) Model in order to get the vektor-representation of each word from this Pre-trained word2vec model instead of my own word2vec model:

```py
vectores = []

for word in first_tuple_elements:
    vectores.append(word_vectors_wiki_gigaword["word"])

print(vectores)
```

This gave me a list of arrays for each word.

Right now I am struggling to link the arrays(vektor representations) to the associated word..
What I want to have is a list of tuples that I can the use for k means clustering:

```
[
 ('event', array([...,...,..]), 
 ('date', array([...,...,..]), 
etc....
]
```

I think that with this kind of list of tuples I might be able to do k means clustering, but I also might be wrong...

Comment: Why bother training your own word-vectors, if in the end you want to use vectors from someone else's trained model? (If training on your own data is a good idea – as it often is – you could just keep & use those word-vectors for your later steps.) What format you should get the words into will depend on what KMeans library you'll be using. (And, I'm not sure you'll need the format you've described.) Which KMeans are you planning to use?

Comment: I am using nltk for k means clustering. I already solved my problem by using a format containing just the arrays and sort the clusters after clustering to the words.